# How to remove controller and action name from URL in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

How can I write working router:connect to have SEO friendly links?

In my site, I have articles and category. In right sidebar article's category is listed with below link.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(ucwords($data['Category']['name']),array('controller'=>'Articles','action'=>'displayArticles','cat'=>$data['Category']['name'])) ?>
```

This gives me link like - http://example.com/Articles/displayArticles/category-name , now I want the link as http://example.com/category-name. So for that I have tried below code but its not working.

```
Router::connect(
    '/:query/*', array('controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'displayArticles'), array(
        'params' => array('query', 'cat'),
        'named' => array(
            'query', 'cat'
        )
    )
);
```

So please someone let me know, how to achieve just category name(parameter) in URL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Router::connect(
    '/:query',
   array('controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'displayArticles',1)
    array('query' => '[a-zA-Z]+')
);
```

Here id is numeric with regex.
**please see [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)**

You will also have to give parameter count in router.

Comment: Thanks, its working but not in the way expected. Now its redirecting for all controller to subscriber which are not defined using Router::connect(). Please suggest another solutions. Can you please also add the sample $this->Html->link() ?

Is it possible to do it .htaccess?